# How to fix error: package 'tzdb' is not available for this version of R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm new at R and trying to usetidyverse. The installation seems to go fine, but when I want to load the package, I get this error: there is no package called 'tzdb'. When I try to install 'tzdb' I get a warning that package 'tzdb' is not available for this version of R. I'm using version 4.0.5, which I believe should work.

Any suggestions on how I can get this package to work (so I can start using tidyverse)?

Edit: I've added an image of the code I ran + the outputs of `sessionInfo()` , `options("repos")` and  `.libPaths()` below.  (I'm sorry I can't copy paste code nor use the browser of the virtual machine that I work from).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hra1r.png

It does give a warning stating that the CRAN mirror is set to an insecure URL. Could that be the problem? It didnt't seem matter for the other packages.

Comment: Can you give us some additional information regarding your operating system as well as the code you use to install `tidyverse` and `tzdb` and the full error message.

Comment: I'm working via a virtual desktop that runs on windows server 2019 datacenter. I used the following code:
> install.packages("tidyverse")

Comment: That error might mean several things, including that the internet connection is blocked or "glitched". If you are able to install other packages (meaning it isn't necessarily the network connection), it might also suggest that your `options("repos")` is pointing to a repository that doesn't contain all of the packages you want/need. It would help to provide the output from `sessionInfo()` or `sessioninfo::session_info()`, as well as `options("repos")` and perhaps `.libPaths()` (I'm stretching here).

Comment: I'm working via a virtual desktop that runs on windows server 2019 datacenter. I used the following code:
> install.packages("tidyverse")
> library(tidyverse)

Then i get:
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'tidyverse':
.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'readr', details:
call: loadnamespace(name)
error: there is no package called 'tzdb' 

So i tried installing 'tzdb':
> install.packages("tzdb")

And then i get:

Warning in install.packages:
package 'tzdb' is not available for this version of R

Comment: Can you add the (truncated for privacy) outputs of `options("repos")` `.libPaths()` as r2evans asked. tzdb should be available for R 4.0.5 (it requires R > 3.3). You could also try `install.packages("tzdb", type="source")` (might throw an error that points us in the right direction.

Comment: I added the output as a picture to the question (unfortunately i can't actually copy anything from the virtual machine i'm coding in). It gives a warning that  the CRAN mirror is set to an insecure URL. Could that be the problem?